# Sass --watch breaking after Yosemite update

Tags: rubygems, sass, command-line-interface, osx-yosemite

After updating to Yosemite on my Macbook Pro, sass --watch no longer functions. I get the following:

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal-1.2.5
Ignoring ffi-1.9.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.5
Ignoring ffi-1.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.3
Ignoring json-1.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json-1.8.1
Ignoring libxml-ruby-2.7.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine libxml-ruby-2.7.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri-1.6.3.1
Ignoring psych-2.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych-2.0.6
```

"gem pristine" doesn't do anything. I tried on Sass 3.4.5 and 3.4.6. Unsure how to resolve.

Comment: Just got a part of this bug this morning, also on a mac book pro + Yosemite. `Warning: Ignoring ffi-1.9.3...`

Answer (score 8):

Iv'e encountered the same issue, this next command helped me, try typing 'gem pristine --all', no idea what it does but it fixed everything.

Comment: One can also consider doing a `gem pristine` specific for the dependency that is broken, as opposed to `--all`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as an "answer" per se due to the scorched earth nature of the solution. I noticed it was working fine on my home MBP, which had significantly fewer gems installed. I really didn't have time to check on my work machine which ones could have been interfering, so I uninstalled all gems using the instructions [here](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-uninstall-all-ruby-gems/). I had to reinstall XCode CLI afterward and `gem install listen` because I likely lost that from the previous instructions (was getting "sass watch is listening for changes" warning every time), and it compiles just fine now.

I realize that may not be a practical answer for others who may use their gems extensively (I don't, I probably just had a lot from following a myriad of tutorials), but this worked for me. I'm not the most experienced CL user, and I know I probably should be using RVM or something, but in any case, this did the trick.